# I submitted my BSc. Special thesis without page numbers

Tags: thesis, paper-submission

I didn't notice that the page numbers had somehow been removed from my thesis before submission. I just saw this.

The day before I had included all the correctly formatted page numbers and set up the ToC. Finally the ToC had the correct numbers but my footers had been removed!

Should I try to send a new amended one with numbers in spite of the marks being cut off or not? How much is either of these options going to affect my supervisor and other's opinion of me? How serious is this of a mistake?

Please help

Comment: This is unanswerable by strangers on the internet. Ask your supervisor and/or the staff at your uni what to do.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to find out how serious this is considered. I did ask. Thanks.

Comment: To give an anecdote, I once handed in a BSc. thesis where due to some font encoding error the printed version was missing all the $\sum$-symbols. The supervisor and I had a laugh about it, made sure the pdf I sent him did not have the same problem and that was it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't know. For me something like missing page numbers does not play a major role in determining the grade, but it may tip the scale if I am uncertain about what grade to give. Submitting a thesis late (or resubmitting it late) also leads to a reduction in grade. So we don't know which course of action is better.

If it is quickly after the submission date, I would be open to a student contacting me and asking what to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's very serious as mistakes happen and this doesn't affect your knowledge and understanding of your subject. I wouldn't let this affect the mark, and I think mine is a majority position, but not knowing your supervisor and university we can't know, and stranger things have happened.

It is somewhat annoying for reading and marking though, so I recommend to contact your supervisor as soon as possible (the longer you wait, the longer they have to deal with a version without page numbers), tell them what has happened, and offer to send them a version with page numbers. If something like this happens, it can leave a positive impression if you recognise your error and are proactive to rectify it. Also it would be helpful to anyone who reads the thesis.

Comment: Yes, I did manage to sort it somewhat. Thank you for your input!

Comment: How to write a proper text (There is an introduction with a research question, there is a review of past literature, folowed by a discussion of your theory (past research is not the same as theory!!!!), etc.) is very much part of the curriculum at my department. This does include things like adding page numbers. So at the end of their studies the students are supposed to know this, and they will be graded on it. It is not the main thing they will be graded on, but it does have an effect on their grade.

Answer (score 0):

It is annoying to referee a large document without page numbers, since this makes it difficult and annoying to clearly identify the parts of the work on which you are giving feeback.  For that reason, I would strongly  recommend reprinting and resubmission.  Check with your supervisor first, but that is probably the best option.  While I can't speak for the academics in charge of this matter, I probably would not impose a marking penalty for this, even if the corrected version comes after the deadline (but within a reasonable time).  On the other hand, I suspect that a referee might heavily criticise the absence of page numbers in a review.